# What is the best way to dry out this ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I would like to DRY out this code. Is the best solution to do it like in rails with before_action method?

```
class Direction
    attr_accessor :dir

    def initialize(dir)
     @dir = dir
    end

    DIRECTIONS = %w[N E S W]

    def turn_left
     d = DIRECTIONS.find_index(dir)
     @dir = DIRECTIONS.rotate!(d-1).first
    end

    def turn_right
     d = DIRECTIONS.find_index(dir)
     @dir = DIRECTIONS.rotate!(d+1).first
    end
end
```

Comment: some controller code would be useful.

Comment: It may make more sense to separate state here from the Direction concept. This sort of confuses two things in one, the definition of your cardinal directions and the storage of the directional state.

Comment: You can simplify your methods by using `dir` instead of `@dir` because you have `attr_accessor :dir`.

Comment: "Is it possible to do it in ruby like in rails"? You do realize that Rails *IS* Ruby code, right? So, of course it's possible.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes I realize that, of course. My question was wrong. I ment is that the best solution for drying out example code? But I see now a lot of good answers...

Comment: Calling `rotate!` modifies the array your `DIRECTIONS` constant is referring to. Don't do that – constants aren't supposed to chance.

Comment: I agree with @Stefan on `rotate!`, and even `rotate` is not good, because it creates new array, which in this case is unnecessary work (see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58873095/6231376) to learn how to avoid `rotate`).

Comment: Thank you all for your help, tips and answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using hashes, mostly for readability.

```
class Direction
  NEXT_LEFT  = { 'N'=>'W', 'W'=>'S', 'S'=>'E', 'E'=>'N' }
  NEXT_RIGHT = NEXT_LEFT.invert

  attr_reader :dir

  def initialize(dir)
    @dir = dir
  end

  def turn_left
    turn(NEXT_LEFT)
  end

  def turn_right
    turn(NEXT_RIGHT)
  end

  private

  def turn(nxt)
    @dir = nxt[@dir]
  end
end
```

```
d = Direction.new('N')
d.dir
  #=> "N" 
d.turn_left
  #=> "W" 
d.turn_left
  #=> "S" 
d.turn_right
  #=> "W"
```

Note:

```
NEXT_RIGHT
  #=> {"W"=>"N", "S"=>"W", "E"=>"S", "N"=>"E"}
```

Comment: Nice and simple, makes it very self documenting too! I'd give the answer to your code as it's about as DRY as it can get. I'd probably add a `turn_around` method too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Direction
  DIRECTIONS = %w[N E S W].freeze
  OPERATIONS = { left: :-, right: :+ }.freeze
  private_constant :DIRECTIONS, :OPERATIONS

  def initialize(dir)
    @dir = dir
  end

  OPERATIONS.keys.each do |turn_direction| # turn_left, turn_right 
    define_method "turn_#{turn_direction}" do
      turn(turn_direction)
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :dir

  def direction_index
    DIRECTIONS.find_index(dir)
  end

  def turn(operation)
    DIRECTIONS.rotate(direction_index.public_send(OPERATIONS[operation], 1)).first
  end
end

p Direction.new('N').turn_left  # "W"
p Direction.new('E').turn_left  # "N"
p Direction.new('S').turn_left  # "E"
p Direction.new('W').turn_left  # "S"
p Direction.new('N').turn_right # "E"
p Direction.new('E').turn_right # "S"
p Direction.new('S').turn_right # "W"
p Direction.new('W').turn_right # "N"
```

You can:

- `freeze` your constants to avoid modifications.
- Change the visibility of your constants if they're not being used outside the `Direction` class.
- Change the visibility of `dir` if you're only using it within the class itself.
- Create an `OPERATIONS` hash, which defines the direction and the operation it'll use to return the next direction.
- Iterate over the `OPERATIONS` keys to dynamically define the methods `turn_left` and `turn_right`.
- Define a `direction_index` method, which returns the index in `DIRECTIONS` by using `dir`.
- Define a turn method, which receives an `operation` parameter:

  - Using `operation` you can get the operation from `OPERATIONS` which tells how to rotate (positive or negative).
  - Applying the method `-` or `+` to the result of `direction_index` you get the arguments to rotate.
  - After that you invoke `rotate` on `DIRECTIONS` and get the first element.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good answers,  but a simple direct solution would be to just factor out the part that is common between the two methods into a turn method and pass in `1` or `-1`.

```
class Direction
  attr_accessor :dir

  def initialize(dir)
    @dir = dir
  end

  DIRECTIONS = %w[N E S W]

  def turn(delta_d)
    d = DIRECTIONS.find_index(dir)
    @dir = DIRECTIONS.rotate!(d + delta_d).first
  end

  def turn_left
    turn(-1)
  end

  def turn_right
    turn(1)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always implement a direction map independent of the state:

```
class DirectionMap
  def initialize(*list)
    # Create a Hash mapping table with left and right directions
    # pre-computed. This uses modulo to "wrap" the array around.
    @directions = list.map.with_index do |dir, i|
      [ dir, [ list[(i - 1) % list.length], list[(i + 1) % list.length] ] ]
    end.to_h
  end

  # These methods use dig to avoid blowing up on an invalid direction,
  # instead just returning nil for garbage input.
  def left(dir)
    @directions.dig(dir, 0)
  end

  def right(dir)
    @directions.dig(dir, 1)
  end
end
```

Where you can now navigate arbitrary compass mappings:

```
map = DirectionMap.new(*%w[ N E S W ])

map.left('N') # => 'W'
map.left(map.left('N')) # => 'S'

map.right('N') # => 'E'
map.right(map.left('N')) # => 'N'
```

So you can do `%w[ N NE E SE S SW W NW ]` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can avoid all the work of creating new array each time you turn (by calling `rotate` on it). Just store your current direction as an index of its letter in the array. Turning is just modular arithmetic on the index (note that in Ruby `-1 % 4 == 3`). And when you want the letter of the direction, just get it from the array using the index.

```rb
class Direction
  DIRECTIONS = %w[N E S W].freeze

  def initialize(dir)
    self.dir = dir
  end

  # dir getter
  def dir
    DIRECTIONS[@dir_index]
  end

  # dir setter
  def dir=(dir)
    @dir_index = DIRECTIONS.index(dir)
  end

  # turning logic
  def turn(delta)
    @dir_index = (@dir_index + delta) % DIRECTIONS.size
    dir
  end

  def turn_left
    turn(-1)
  end

  def turn_right
    turn(1)
  end
end

p Direction.new('N').turn_left   #=> "W"
p Direction.new('E').turn_left   #=> "N"
p Direction.new('S').turn_left   #=> "E"
p Direction.new('W').turn_left   #=> "S"
p Direction.new('N').turn_right  #=> "E"
p Direction.new('E').turn_right  #=> "S"
p Direction.new('S').turn_right  #=> "W"
p Direction.new('W').turn_right  #=> "N"
```